# How to remove repeated letters in java using (Regular Expressions) and being case Insensitive

Tags: java, regex, case-insensitive

I have been trying to do is to replace any repeated letters with the lower case version of their letter (in java). For example:

I want a function that maps:

```
bob -> bob
bOb -> bob
bOOb -> bob
bOob -> bob
boOb -> bob
bob -> bob
Bob -> Bob
bOb -> bob
```

However, I have been not successful to do this using regexs (in Java).

I have tried the following:

```
    String regex = "([A-za-z])\\1+";
    String str ="bOob";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex , Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("$1"));
```

However, this returns bOb and not bob. (it works on boOb).

I also tried:

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)([A-Za-z0-9])(?=\\1)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        return matcher.replaceAll("");
```

This solve one problem, now bOob -> bob but brings another problem because now it maps boOb to bob.

NOTE: it should also map BOobOoboObOoObooOoOoOoOoOOb -> Bobobobobob.

I feel that at this point it might just be easier to loop over the string and do some logic based on each character but I just didn't want to give up using regexs... If there exists a solution using regexs, is it more likely to be more efficient than a loop going over each character?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I am aware that one could just lower case everything before passing the string, though, thats not what I wanted because it maps:

Bob -> bob

Comment: You want to map bOb -> bob but also Bob -> Bob? you ned to add the requirement that first letters shouldn't be transformed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Matcher#group()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) instead of `$1` here

```
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll(matcher.group(1)
                                          .toLowerCase()));
}
```

Lets you make use of `toLowerCase()` then.

***EDIT** : (in response to OP's comments)*

`Matcher#group(n)` is same as `$n` -- it refers to the *n'th* capture group. So, `group(1)` and `$1` both capture `O` except that you can switch the capture `toLowerCase()`.

The loop is being run by `replaceAll()` not by the `find()`. `Matcher#find()` is required to initialize the groups, so that `group(1)` returns the capture before `replaceAll()` is invoked.

But, this also means the capture stays the same which suffices your requirements but would require the matcher to be reset for a string like *BOobbOobboObbOoObbooOoOoOoOoOOb* (notice the double b's). The loop would have to be driven by `Mathcer#find()` now which means `replaceAll()` gets traded with `replaceFirst()`.

```
String regex = "([A-Za-z])\\1+";
String str = "BOobbOobboObbOoObbooOoOoOoOoOObb";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    str = matcher.replaceFirst(matcher.start() > 0 ? matcher.group(1)
                                    .toLowerCase() : matcher.group(1));
    matcher.reset(str);
}

System.out.println(str); // Bobobobobob
```

[Matcher#start()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start%28%29) is used here to identify if the match is at the start of input where case is left untouched.

Comment: I am impressed and a bit confused at the same time. I was wondering if you could explain a little what .group(1) does? The part I fail to understand is, why you dont have to cyle through the matches, like doing something like:

int i = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll(matcher.group(i).toLowerCase()));
i++;
  }

how is that different from what you did? Also, whats the difference between my $1 and your group(x) function? Im guessing your getting a point to the match and "forcing" a lower case. correct?

Comment: Btw, the reason I am impressed is because it works on exactly what I needed which is mapping BOobOoboObOoObooOoOoOoOoOOb -> Bobobobobob. Very cool.

Comment: @CharlieParker Please, check update. I've added the first letter capital fix as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the code I was looking for (based on the accepted answer):

```
public String removeRepeatedLetters(String str, boolean caseSensitive){
    if(caseSensitive){
        return this.removeRepeatedLetters(str); //uses case sensitive version
    }else{
        Pattern patternRep = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z])(\\1+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = patternRep.matcher(str);
        String output = str;
        while(matcher.find()){
            String matchStr = matcher.group(1);
            output = matcher.replaceFirst(matchStr.toLowerCase());
            matcher = patternRep.matcher(output);
            matcher.reset();
        }
        return output;
    }   
}
```

What it does is replace any repeated letters (whether caps or not caps) and replaces them with a single non-caps one.

I think is very close to working as I want it to, though it maps Bbob -> bob. I doubt that because its not mapping to Bob, it would affect too much the reason I am using this.

btw, if anyone can see how to optimize this, feel free to comment! It does annoy me a little the .reset(), though I am not sure if its neccesary.

Comment: Ah, I was in the middle of updating my answer when you posted. Please, have another look. It's more or less same except you can avoid creating a new `Matcher` every time. I've added the fix to keep the first letter as it is too.